# Carregar informação dentro da lambda e usar no foreach da lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Criei uma propriedade na classe `CatalogItemResponse` para usar em um método, mas o boss pediu para tirar. Acontece que eu preciso dela para carregar outra propriedade e sem ela não estou conseguindo. Esse é meu Left:

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)

            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
            {
                ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,
                //DistributionCenterErpId = final.Product.DistributionCenterErpId,
                //Atribuições
                .......
             }).ToList();
```

Essa é a propriedade que removi da classe: `DistributionCenterErpId`, sendo populada na linha comentada no Left. Então no ForEach da lambda, dou um `new Product()`, e claro, mato os valores de `Product`, tendo que repopulá-lo novamente dessa forma:

```
qry.ForEach(q =>
            {
                var product = new Product();

                product.CategoryId = q.CategoryId;
                product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;
                product.HaveMaximumPercentage = q.HaveMaximumPercentage;
                product.HaveMinimumPercentage = q.HaveMinimumPercentage;
                product.Hidden = q.Hidden;
                product.ChildrenCategoryId = q.ChildrenCategoryId;
                product.Description = q.Description;
                //product.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId;
                //Mais atribuições e etc
});
```

Observe que comentei essa linha `product.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId` pois não tenho mais o campo `q.DistributionCenterErpId` na classe e obviamente vai dar erro nesse ponto. Como eu faço para pegar o valor do campo no Left e depois atribuir(usar) no ForEach repopulando Product nessa propriedade? Há como?

**EDIT1**

Fiz um new anônimo, ok, consigo colocar qualquer propriedade. Porem dois problemas. O retorno do método é um `List<CatalogItemResponse>` e como dei um anônimo, perdi essa referência e não sei o que fazer para retornar e não sei como trazer `Product` no ForEach. Sei que q é tipo anônimo que tem propriedade de `Product` já preenchido, mas não sei como atribuir isso. Assim ficou a lambda com o tipo anônimo e o return com erro.

```
    public List<CatalogItemResponse> GetAllCatalog(int resellerId)
            {
                var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
                p => p.CategoryId,
                c => c.Id,
                (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)

                .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
                (final, c) => new
                {
                    ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,

                    DolarRate = 0.0m,
                    ResellerPriceUSD = 0.0m,
                    ResellerPriceBRL = 0.0m,
                    BasePriceBRL = 0.0m,
                    BasePriceUSD = 0.0m,

                    CategoryId = final.Product.CategoryId,
                    CategoryName = (c != null ? c.Name : null),
                    PictureId = final.Product.PictureId,
                    Description = final.Product.Description,
                    ShortDescription = final.Product.ShortDescription,
                    Name = final.Product.Name,
                    NameHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(final.Product.NameHtml) ? final.Product.Name : final.Product.NameHtml,
                    PartNumber = final.Product.PartNumber,
                    Hidden = final.Product.Hidden,
                    Order = final.Product.Order,
                    HaveMaximumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage,
                    MaximumPercentage = final.Product.MaximumPercentage,
                    HaveMinimumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage,
                    MinimumPercentage = final.Product.MinimumPercentage,
                    AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
                    AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
                    StandardMarkup = final.Product.StandardMarkup,
                    DistributionCenterErpId = final.Product.DistributionCenterErpId,
                    PictureFilename = final.Product.Picture.FileName

                }).ToList();

                qry.ForEach(q =>
                {
                    var catalogo = new CatalogItemResponse();
                    var product = new Product();

                    catalogo.CategoryId = q.CategoryId;
                    catalogo.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                    catalogo.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;
                    catalogo.HaveMaximumPercentage = q.HaveMaximumPercentage;
                    catalogo.HaveMinimumPercentage = q.HaveMinimumPercentage;
                    catalogo.Hidden = q.Hidden;
                    catalogo.ChildrenCategoryId = q.ChildrenCategoryId;
                    catalogo.Description = q.Description;
                    //catalogo.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId;
                    catalogo.MaximumPercentage = q.MaximumPercentage;
                    catalogo.MinimumPercentage = q.MinimumPercentage;
                    catalogo.Name = q.Name;
                    catalogo.NameHtml = q.NameHtml;
                    catalogo.Order = q.Order;
                    catalogo.PartNumber = q.PartNumber;
                    catalogo.PictureId = q.PictureId;
                    catalogo.ShortDescription = q.ShortDescription;
                    catalogo.StandardMarkup = q.StandardMarkup;  

                    var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);
                    catalogo.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);

                    product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                    product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;

//Continua fazendo assim, propriedade a propriedade ou tem outra forma de preencher Product???

                    var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

                    if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                        catalogo.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                    catalogo.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                    catalogo.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                    catalogo.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                    catalogo.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;

                });

                return qry;
```

**EDIT2**

Fiz outra alteração na query, para não ser necessário recarregar Product no ForEach. O problema é que eu não sei como passar um objeto Product no parâmetro do método, desse método: `var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;`. A nova query ficou assim

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)

            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new
            { final.Product, c }).ToList();

            var query = qry;

            qry.ForEach(q =>
            {
                var catalogo = new CatalogItemResponse();

                catalogo.CategoryId = q.Product.CategoryId;
                catalogo.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = q.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration;
                catalogo.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = q.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration;
                catalogo.HaveMaximumPercentage = q.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage;
                catalogo.HaveMinimumPercentage = q.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage;
                catalogo.Hidden = q.Product.Hidden;
                catalogo.ChildrenCategoryId = q.Product.ChildrenCategoryId;
                catalogo.Description = q.Product.Description;
                //catalogo.DistributionCenterErpId = q.DistributionCenterErpId;
                catalogo.MaximumPercentage = q.Product.MaximumPercentage;
                catalogo.MinimumPercentage = q.Product.MinimumPercentage;
                catalogo.Name = q.Product.Name;
                catalogo.NameHtml = q.Product.NameHtml;
                catalogo.Order = q.Product.Order;
                catalogo.PartNumber = q.Product.PartNumber;
                catalogo.PictureId = q.Product.PictureId;
                catalogo.ShortDescription = q.Product.ShortDescription;
                catalogo.StandardMarkup = q.Product.StandardMarkup;               

                var parentProducts = _productService.GetParentsOf(q.Product.Id).Select(x => x.PartNumber);
                catalogo.Parents.AddRange(parentProducts);               

                var price = _erpPriceService.GetPrice(product, 1, resellerId).Result;

                if (price.BasePriceUSD > 0)
                    catalogo.DolarRate = price.BasePriceBRL / price.BasePriceUSD;

                catalogo.ResellerPriceUSD = price.ResellerPriceUSD;
                catalogo.ResellerPriceBRL = price.ResellerPriceBRL;
                catalogo.BasePriceBRL = price.BasePriceBRL;
                catalogo.BasePriceUSD = price.BasePriceUSD;

            });

            return qry;
```

qry não é mais do tipo CatalogItemResponse e não sei como atribuir um CatalogItemResponse no return

**EDIT3**

No início do método fiz isso:

```
var listaResponse = new List<CatalogItemResponse>();
```

E dentro do ForEach, após todas as atribuições, fiz isso

```
listaResponse.Add(catalogo);
```

E retornei isso

```
return listaResponse;
```

Se é isso que deveria fazer, só falta jogar `Product` no `ForEach` e não estou sabendo fazer

Comment: Pode usar reflexão, ou o `Automapper`